# How to delete last etl_date records in ODI 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, etl

I am new at ODI 11g and I make development a report by using ODI 11g.
Everything is well so far.
However, I would like to delete last three months (etl_date) from the final table. How can I do that with ODI?

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ETL_DATE IN (TO_DATE(#ETL_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(#ETL_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), -1), ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(#ETL_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), -2));
```

Comment: In what way does your current code produce unwanted results?

Comment: Report table runs truncate-insert for now. I'd like to change it, first delete last three months data then insert the new rows.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions 
1) You can create ODI procedure with code above and put it before or after interface (as you wish) 
2) Customize your IKM module putting condition in deletion step 
[image: sample step]

```
delete from <%=odiRef.getTable("L","TARG_NAME","A")%> where 1=1
<%=odiRef.getOption("DELETE_FILTER")%>
```